# Клиент-серверное приложение "чат"

Tags: клиент-сервер, c++

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение "чат". В каком месте и как нужно задать обмен между клиентами. В качестве примера для разбора взяла "эхо-сервер" вот [отсюда](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/006/006r.shtml).

Как сделать, чтобы сообщения рассылались с сервера другим клиентам?

Comment: Почему бы не попробовать Qt? http://qt-doc.ru/model-klient-server.html http://habrahabr.ru/post/131585/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Дарьялла](/users/7513/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0), посмотрел на [пример "эхо-сервера"](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/006/006r.shtml)

Откровенно, мне кажется что для чата (насколько понимаю чат) функция потока SexToClient() не совсем подходит. Собственно оттуда надо оставить

```
while ((bytes_recv = recv(my_sock, &buff[0], sizeof(buff), 0)) &&
bytes_recv != SOCKET_ERROR)
```

а вот вместо одного send() надо сделать цикл, отправляющий полученное сообщение всем участникам, т.е. на все сокеты, полученные из accept () (и еще не закрытые).

Видимо для этого нужно сделать внешний список (или массив) полученных сокетов. Новый сокет, получаемый из accept() в main() заносить туда в  SexToClient() перед циклом while.

Соответственно SexToClient(), выходя из  своего while (по bytes_recv == 0 или SOCKET_ERROR) должна удалять этот сокет из общего списка.

Работа с этим списком, естественно д.б. синхронизирована мьютексом.

Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так: в эхо-сервере ф-я send(my_sock, &buff[0], bytes_recv, 0); должна my_sock ассоциировать с адресом клиента-получателя сообщения. Для этого целесообразно создавать массив или временный файл с четырьмя параметрами в записи (строке): имя клиента отправителя - ip  имя клиента получателя - ip. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

роль сервера в том, чтобы "слушать" когда к нему присоединятся клиенты, а роль клиента в том, чтобы инициировать соединения, зная адрес сервера. Когда соединение уже произошло на этом этапе различие клиента и сервера заканчиваются - посылка и прием сообщений и на сервере и на клиенте одними и теми же функциями - recv и send. Один и тот же процесс может включать в себя и клиента и сервера. Если же брать понятие сервера в смысле как узел интернета со своим дэнээс-именем (а клиенты - простые людишки), то роль ТАКОГО сервера чтобы иметь список всех клиентов-людишек, соответствия их логинам и выдавать эти списки (можно частично) клиентам-людишкам, так, чтобы они могли соединиться между собой по принципы клиент-сервер уже в сокетовском смысле. Поэтому важно не путать понятие сервер в первом и втором смыслах.